# Help with Key-Value-Observing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

I need a bit of help with KVO, I'm about half way there. What I'm trying to do is trigger a method when something in an Tree Controller changes.

So I 'm using this code to register as a KVO.

```
[theObject addObserver: self
            forKeyPath: @"myKeyPath"
               options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
               context: NULL];
```

But how do i trigger a method when the Key Path I am observing changes?

One extra question, when I add my self as an Observer I want the Key Path to be a Property in my Core Data model, Have I done that correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` to dispatch the method you wish to call.

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    NSDictionary *dispatch;
    ...
}
@end
@implementation Foo
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        dispatch = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(somethingHappenedTo:with:)),@"myKeyPath",...,nil] retain];
        ...
    }
}
...
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
            ofObject:(id)object
            change:(NSDictionary *)change
            context:(void *)context
{
    SEL msg = NSSelectorFromString([dispatch objectForKey:keyPath]);
    if (msg) {
        [self performSelector:msg withObject:object withObject:keyPath];
    }
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}
...
```

See "[Receiving Notification of a Change](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Concepts/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-179866)" for details.

Comment: "NSDictionary dispatch;" should be "NSDictionary *dispatch;", but otherwise good.

Comment: D'oh. Fixed. Also changed "performSelector" to "performSelector:withObject:withObject", for a more generally useful approach.

Comment: One extra question, when I add my self as an Observer I want the Key Path to be a Property in my Core Data model, Have I done that correctly?

Comment: @Joshua: the property name sounds like the correct key path, for common applications of KVO. If you're doing something uncommon, however...

Comment: I see, I don't get any errors but it the selector doesn't work. Here's a Picture of the code … http://snapplr.com/0q5f

Comment: Does `dispatch` have an entry for each key path you're observing? I updated the example to include this.

Comment: I believe you want to wrap those selectors in NSSelectorFromString and NSStringFromSelector. I don't think the above will compile, not w/o warnings anyway. and we all use -Wall, right? ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have updated my code by wrapping the selector with NSSelectorFromString but I still have some warnings. http://snapplr.com/aeh5

Comment: Duh, SELs aren't objects. Anyone know why not? Nevermind... this *is* SO, so I'll just post a new question.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you take a look at the Google Toolbox For Mac's [GTMNSObject+KeyValueObserving.h](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSObject%2BKeyValueObserving.h) category or at least the blog [post](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/key-value-observing-done-right.html) by Michael Ash that inspired it. Basically, doing manual KVO right is *very* subtle and the pattern suggested by the API is not ideal. It's much better to put an other layer on the API (as GTMNSObject+KeyValueObserving) does that makes things more like the `NSNotification` API and hides some of the sources of subtle bugs.

Using GTMNSObject+KeyValueObserving, you would do

```
[theObject gtm_addObserver:self
                forKeyPath:@"myKeyPath"
                  selector:@selector(myCallbackSelector:)
                  userInfo:nil
                   options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew];
```

and your `-myCallbackSelector:` will get called when the value at `@"myKeyPath"` changes with an argument of type `GTMKeyValueChangeNotification`, which encapsulates all the relevant information you might need.

This way, you don't have to have a big dispatch table in `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context` (in reality one is maintained for you by the category) or have to worry about the correct way to use the `context` pointer to avoid conflict with super/sub classes etc.

Comment: That looks interesting, where do I download the code/framework?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/

GTM is, like the boost C++ libraries, a take-what-you-want architecture. They recommend that you include the files/classes you want directly into your own project. There are only a couple of common includes.

Answer (score 4):

You should implement this and it will be invoked when the keypath changes:

```
 (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                     ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change
                      context:(void *)context;
```

More info [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Concepts/KVOBasics.html).

Answer (score 3):

( this is a technique I learned here: http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1999 )

You could pass the method in the 'context', like

```
[theObject addObserver:self 
            forKeyPath:@"myKeyPath"
               options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
               context:@selector(doSomething)];
```

..then in the observeValueForKeyPath method, you cast it to the SEL selector type, and then perform it.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    SEL selector = (SEL)context;
    [self performSelector:selector];
}
```

If you want to pass data to the doSomething method you could use the 'new' key in the 'change' dictionary, like this:

```
[theObject addObserver:self 
              forKeyPath:@"myKeyPath"
                 options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                 context:@selector(doSomething:)]; // note the colon

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
    {
        SEL selector = (SEL)context;

        // send the new value of observed keyPath to the method
        [self performSelector:selector withObject:[change valueForKey:@"new"]]; 
    }


-(void)doSomething:(NSString *)newString // assuming it's a string
{
      label.text = newString;
}
```